# Inner class access to outer class nested enum

Tags: c++, enums, scope, inner-classes

In the following code fragment, why does 'A' in the inner class `CheckForA` method not have to be a qualified-id (i.e., `return myE == Outer::A`)? Is it because both E and Inner are in the same scope? Does class scope work like namespace scope?

```
class Outer 
{
public:
   enum E{ A, B, C };

   class Inner
   {
   public:
      void Set( E e_ ) { myE = e_; }
      bool CheckForA() const { return myE == A; }
      E myE;
   };

   void Set( E e_ ) { myInner.Set(e_); }
   bool CheckForA() const { return myInner.CheckForA(); };

   Inner myInner;
};


int main()
{
   Outer outer;
   outer.Set(Outer::A);

   return (int)outer.CheckForA();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 9.7 Nested class declarations
>
> 1 A class can be declared within another class. A class declared
>   within another is called a nested class. The name of a nested class is
>   local to its enclosing class. **The nested class is in the scope of
>   its enclosing class.**